# string combinations of 0 and 1

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this question in an interview:

> Given a string s consisting of `0`, `1` and `?`. The question mark can
>   be either `0` or `1`. Find all possible combinations for the string.

I came up with below code but I wanted to know whether it is the best way to solve the problem and also I am confuse on the time complexity?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    addCombinations("0?1?", 0, output);
    System.out.println(output);
  }

  private static void addCombinations(String input, int index, List<String> output) {
    for (int i = index; i < input.length(); ++i) {
      if (input.charAt(i) == '?') {
        addCombinations(input.substring(0, i) + "0" + input.substring(i + 1), i + 1, output);
        addCombinations(input.substring(0, i) + "1" + input.substring(i + 1), i + 1, output);
        return;
      }
    }
    output.add(input);
  }
```

Comment: Do you have to list them or simply compute the number?

Comment: we have to list all the possible outputs

Comment: Then I think this question belongs to CodeReview, not StackOverflow.

Comment: If the string has length `n` and `m` are ? then this should take `O(n * 2^m)` time and memory.  You cannot do better on time, and the only way to improve on memory is to print as you find combinations rather than accumulate them in a list.

Comment: To expand on btilly's comment: the number of possible combinations given `m` question marks is `2^m`. So if there is one `?` in the string, then there are only two possible outputs. If there are two `?` in the string, four outputs, etc. And since there are `n` characters in the string, the total number of output characters is `n * 2^n`.

Comment: why this `the number of possible combinations given m question marks is 2^m` is `2^m`?

Comment: Also is there any better way by which we can rewrite this recursion logic?

Comment: Imagine they're all question marks. For example, `??`. The possibilities are `00,01,10,11`. Now, say it's `1??`. There's still only 4 possible combinations. That's 2^2. With 3 question marks, there are 8 (2^3) possibilities.

Comment: See also: [string combinations of 0 and 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223463/string-combinations-of-0-and-1).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is best or not.  If it works, is understandable, and doesn't have extremely poor performance then it's probably fine.

Here is a simple one that I wrote that uses some bookkeeping to keep track of the positions to be filled.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> bitStrings = generate("0?1?0?11");
      bitStrings.forEach(System.out::println);
   }

   public static List<String> generate(String pattern) {
      List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

      //Starting bit template
      String start = pattern.replaceAll("\\?", "0");

      //get the changeable positions.
      int[] pos = IntStream.range(0, pattern.length()).filter(
            i -> pattern.charAt(i) == '?').toArray();

      // Now simply iterate thru the 2^n possibilities where
      // n is the number of changeable positions.
      for (int i = 0; i < 1 << pos.length; i++) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(start);
         int p = i;
         for (int k = 0; k < pos.length; k++) {
            sb.setCharAt(pos[k], (char) ((p & 1) + '0'));
            p >>= 1;
         }
         output.add(sb.toString());
      }
      return output;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a different implementation that doesn't use recursion and doesn't use string concatenation.

```
private static List<String> addCombinations(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> wildcardIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == '?') {
            wildcardIndex.add(i);
            chars[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    if (wildcardIndex.size() > 31)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many wildcards (max 31): " + wildcardIndex.size());
    // Collections.reverse(wildcardIndex);
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>(1 << wildcardIndex.size());
    NEXT: for (;;) {
        output.add(new String(chars));
        for (int i : wildcardIndex) {
            if (chars[i] == '0') {
                chars[i] = '1';
                continue NEXT;
            }
            chars[i] = '0';
        }
        break;
    }
    return output;
}
```

*Test 1*

```
List<String> output = addCombinations("0?1?");
System.out.println(output);
```

```
[0010, 0110, 0011, 0111]
```

*Test 2*

```
System.out.println(addCombinations("???"));
```

```
[000, 100, 010, 110, 001, 101, 011, 111]
```

*Test 3 (with `reverse()` call uncommented)*

```
System.out.println(addCombinations("???"));
```

```
[000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```

Answer (score -1):

If number of questions mark in the given string is m, the possible number of combination is 2^m.
So why ?

For "?" Answer is "0","1"

For "??" Answer is "00","01","1,0","11" (Addiding 0 and 1 with every result of "?"=("0","1"))

For "???" Answer is "000","001","010","011","100","101","110","111",(Addiding 0 and 1 with every result of "??")

When number of questions mark is 1,the possible number of combination is 2=2^1.
When number of questions mark is 2,the possible number of combination is 2*2=4=2^2.
When number of questions mark is 3,the possible number of combination is 4*2=8=2^3.
When number of questions mark is 4,the possible number of combination is 8*2=16=2^4.
When number of questions mark is 5,the possible number of combination is 16*2=32=2^5.
When number of questions mark is 6,the possible number of combination is 32*2=64=2^6.
When number of questions mark is 7,the possible number of combination is 64*2=128=2^7.

So when number of questions mark is m,the possible number of combination is 2^m.

As we know from binary system that each number from 0 to (2^m)-1 gives a combination of binary 0 and 1.

So when the length is 1, we can consider 0 to (2^1)-1=1

```
0 0
1 1
```

So when the length is 2, we can consider 0 to (2^2)-1=3

```
0 00
1 01
2 10
3 11
```

So when the length is 3, we can consider 0 to (2^3)-1=7

```
0 000
1 001
2 010
3 011
4 100
5 101
6 110
7 111
```

Similarly for the length m, we can consider 0 to (2^m)-1.

So we can take every number from 0 to (2^m)-1 .

> For each number we will check every bit from 0 to m-1.
>       If the ith bit is 0, we will put 0 in ith '?'.
>       If the ith bit is 1, we will put 1 in ith '?'.

Thus we will get 2^m different strings.